# Get sanpshot form webcam using WPFMediaKit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webcam, wpf-mediakit

I need to capture an image form a WebCam. I'm using WPFMediaKit ([WPFMediaKit on GitHub](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit)), and I can see the webcam video, but I don't found how to take an snapshot.

```
<controls:VideoCaptureElement x:Name="videoCapElement"
                             LoadedBehavior="Play"
                             DesiredPixelWidth="320"
                             DesiredPixelHeight="240"
                             Stretch="Fill"
                             VideoCaptureSource="Camera Name"
                             FPS="30"/>
```

Thanks for yout time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution in this page: [Jason's C# Coding Record -> Capture a photo via WPFMediaKit](http://jasonlin9011.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/capture-photo-via-wpfmediakit.html)

Extract:

```
private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{     
  RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)captureElement.ActualWidth, (int)captureElement.ActualHeight, 96, 96, 
       PixelFormats.Default);
  bmp.Render(captureElement);
  BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
  encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
       encoder.Save(ms);
       CaptureData = ms.ToArray();
  }
  DialogResult = true;
}
```

Thnaks for your time!